# Trigger event when hovering over a particular word in NSTextView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextview, nsattributedstringkey

I need to create a popover when a users hovers over a particular word in `NSTextView` e.g

"The boy owns a ***dog***"

Once the user has the cursor over a `dog` (mouse up with nothing selected), a cocoa event needs to fire so i can perform an action, which is show a popover my case

I thought `NSAttributedString` might be able to help, but don't see any hover events or tracking ability built in.

Comment: How could the cursor be over a word longer than one letter?

Comment: If you are talking about a selection of text, take a look at the `NSTextView`'s `textViewDidChangeSelection` notification method.  By the way, tigger is not an English word.

Comment: Not sure how ```textViewDidChangeSelection``` helps here, as the text has not changed ?

Comment: > How could the cursor be over a word longer than one letter? 

Sorry, don't understand this comment. 
Sorry, don't understand this comment.

Comment: The cursor appears before or after a letter, not over two or more letters.

Comment: Don't blame me for your down vote.  It's not me.

Comment: Np El Tomato, I appreciate you are just looking for clarification.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You need to get the mouse location from `mouseMoved`, then use the `layoutManager` of the `textView` to find the word. I am not near a Mac, so cannot get you an answer. But hopefully these keywords will get you on your way. See my question about something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610163/nslayoutmanager-returns-incorrect-glyphindex-for-mouseposition-in-nstextview

Comment: All you have to do is to use `NSTextView`'s `selectedRange()` along with its `textViewDidChangeSelection` notification method.

Comment: @Jimmy: when you say hover, do you mean with the mouse up (no selection) or down (selection) ?

Comment: Hi @koen,  mouse up (no selection)

Comment: Ok, so see my suggestion above. And please make that clear in your question.

Comment: @koen awesome, your suggestion worked. Do you want to answer and I can accept ?

Comment: @Jimmy Glad it's working. It's perfectly fine if you post the answer yourself, I only pointed you in the right direction. If it was helpful, feel free to up-vote my Q/A in the link I provided.

Comment: @Jimmy could you please provide a code example of your solution?

Answer (score 4):

The possible solution is by using `NSTextAttachment` and `attachmentCell` property.

So here is a way

1. subclass your custom cell from `NSTextAttachmentCell`, so you have access to override `wantsToTrackMouse`, `highlight...` and `trackMouse...` interfaces
2. create empty `NSTextAttachment` (if needed it can also be subclassed) and set your instance of cell to `attachmentCell`
3. add above text attachment to your NSTextStorage (mutable attributed string) in desired word's range with `NSAttributedString.Key.attachment`